# No X3D viewer applications

Tags: 3d, x3d

I know this isn't much of a programming question as such, but I'm doing some research on 3D viewer applications and X3D viewer applications. I've found many 3D viewer apps but only two X3D viewer ones. I was wondering why there's hardly any X3D viewer applications on the market.

**EDIT**

The 3D apps that I've found that I'm okay with the amount that I have are: `i3D Viewer, 3DVIA, 3D Model Viewer, Blue 3D Model Viewer, PortShape, 3D Viewer, Babel3D, Afanche 3D Model Viewer, iRhino, Viso3D` and the X3D ones that I've found are: `FreeX3D, FreeWRL` and I'm looking for more X3D viewer apps

Comment: Could you please provide which viewers you have already found. Maybe people can suggest other ones.

Comment: @Endery I have edited the question with the one's I've found

Answer (score 1):

Find here an opensource multimedia framework that is able to play most of the media files including x3d scenes: https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/

and the source code: https://github.com/gpac/gpac

Answer (score 0):

We are using `BS Contact` from Bitmanagement as VRML/X3D Viewer for our software. You can download a free version if it is not a problem to give away your e-mail address.
http://www.bitmanagement.de/en/download